# How to insert a multipart string into a sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am stuck figuring out how to read a string from serial port, break it into it's parts and insert into a sqlite table.  Below is the code I have so far, but I am missing the correct syntax to load the string correctly into sqlite.  I can't change the incoming value.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#--Arduino code calls this file when it detects flow during standard operation (i.e. when
#--not in calibration mode.  This code simply records the values from the sensor.
import serial
import sqlite3 as sqlite
#import sys

serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200)

code = ''

while True:
    data = serial.read()

    if data == '\r':
        (strdevice,strcount) = code.split(',',1)
        device = strdevice
        count = int(strcount)
        con = sqlite.connect('/mnt/sda1/sensor_flow_moteino.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO data_log (device,count) VALUES(?,?)'''(device,count))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        print(code)
        code = ''

    else:
        code = code + data
```

Incoming data from the serial port is in the form:
"some_string,123" where the first value is a string and the second value is an integer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to `split` the `code` string on the comma: `(somestring, number) = code.split(',', 1)` then do whatever extra processing you need to do with the two parts.

Comment: (For example, you probably want to use `int(number)`, since it will be a string after splitting.)

Comment: @AustinHastings thanks for the suggestions.  I added your comments to the code, but am getting {TypeError: 'str' object is not callable} on the cur.execute line.

Comment: You need a comma after end of 3-quoted string: `'''(device`